# Determine when ASP TextBox is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I cant seem to find an event that is fired when a user clicks on an ASP TextBox. Is there an event that is fired? Is the only way to handle this through javascript? If possible, Id like to do it in the code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no OnClick event raised on the server side when the text element is clicked. You can add an `onclick` handler on javascript an issue a postback to the page. For example:

```
<asp:TextBox onclick="myFunc();" ID="das" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then something like:

```
function myfunc()
{
    var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget; //could be any string 
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;//could be any string
    theForm.submit();
}
```

On the server-side:

```
string eventTarget=Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]; //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the [OnCheckedChanged](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged.aspx&ei=__UmT8u8Ioqgtweft5FA&usg=AFQjCNEWGKbf_911Sv3I6TL7tliIs33d_A&sig2=e7tClQsAL59zYK1jV1YC7g) event but it is only fired on post back unless you have [autopostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback.aspx) set to true.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox doesn't have Click event at server-side.

But, textBox is a web control which supports attributes, so you could in fact use this to create a javascript click action. Either set this on aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnClick="" />
```

or this in code

```
Me.TextBox1.Attributes("onclick") = ""
```